# Understanding backslash in arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute syntax?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I copied this line from Python code, but I don't understand the `\" \"` around the word District.

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Community_areaFC, 
     "NEW_SELECTION", 
     "\"District\" = 3")
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is a Python escape character.  From the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

In your where clause, the field name `District` may need double quotes as the [field delimiter](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm#GUID-04DAAB63-BCB9-4D25-8424-63DDA67DFDCB) (but this varies by datasource).  Because the string literal is surrounded by double quotes, you need to escape the internal double quotes using the backslash so they form part of the string.

For example:

```
print( "ab \"C\" de")
ab "C" de

print( "\"District\" = 3")
"District" = 3
```

However, you can wrap your where clause in single quotes instead, so the internal double quotes don't need escaping:

```
print( 'ab "C" de')
ab "C" de

print( '"District" = 3')
"District" = 3
```

But, if you are querying a string field, then you need to wrap the expression in single quotes so you'll need to use an escape character somewhere:

```
print( "\"District_Name\" = 'Blah'")
"District_Name" = 'Blah'

print( '"District_Name" = \'Blah\'')
"District_Name" = 'Blah'
```

However, you can also use the [`arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) function to avoid this:

```
where_clause = "{} = 3".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(Community_areaFC, "District"))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Community_areaFC, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
```